# framework or saas solution for collecting data

Tags: architecture, saas, lowcode

I have to create an application for data collection and reporting. Collection phase must be quite elastic (many dimmensions and measures based on configurable dictionaries) - simple web interface and API for connectors.
Requirements seems to be quite typpical. I'm wondering if there ready-to-use SaaS solution or maybe framework that I can use as a starting point.
Thanks in advance